# Run multiple processes in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a bash script for the following scenario:

```
nc -lvvp 1334
./c_file
```

c_file creates a reverse connection to the netcat listener. The issue is when I run this bash file only netcat listener starts. c_file is not executed. Can some tell me how to properly implement this?

I have tried the `&` command that runs the process in background but it doesn't work. These must be in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

```
# run the netcat in the background as
nc -lvvp 1334 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nohup` so that if the shell closes, your process doesn't terminate. `&` puts the process in the background.

```
nohup nc -lvvp 1334 &
./c_file
```

You may also do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> to stop the currently running process and then run `bg` to resume it and put it in background. Afterwards you can use `fg` to bring it back in the foreground if you wish.